# How to invite some users say user B,C to view+update the data created by user A using Firebase + Android app

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app powered by Firebase. The app is like a bill splitter app, say the party was organised by a user A and he invited user B,C to the party and B,C both has bought some stuff for the party. Now they want to list down all they bought in the app.

Each particular user of this app has say 3 sub nodes inside its real-time database. Among these 3 nodes, the data present in one of the nodes (say of **user A**) are viewable + editable by some set of other users (say **user B,C**; and these 2 users has been added by user A to his list who can read+write his shared DB info).

**Question 1**: How to invite the **user B,C** to **view+update** the data created by **user A**? What if the app is already installed in B's phone? What if app is not installed in C's phone?

**Question 2**: How to implement the DB structure for each user, keeping the security of the App in mind?

N.B: I am using both Google sign in and phone number verification for auth.

Comment: What kind of app your planning to make please explain in details, and please explain what do you mean by user B, C is created by user A, I am not getting what you are asking

Comment: Hi Rushikesh, Say the app is kind of like a bill splitter app, say the party was organised by user A and he invited user B,C to the party and B,C both has bought some stuff for the party. Now they want to list down all they bought in the app....Its the DATA that was created by user A, which can be viewed+ modified by user B and C. ( the list of users which can view+update A's data can be defined by A only).

Comment: I have added answer, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, I have made some data structure:
[image]

**Answer for question 1::**
In the data structure, I have added child node for User:A -**invitedby** which has the User Id's who sent an invitation to User:A.

So add an activity layout in your User account which has the functionality to show all the user of your system and then functionality to send an invitation by clicking on the particular user. In backend, this is done by taking the invited Users UserId and make updations in its **invitedby** node.

Acoording to example of following data structure, User:F is in your system and it invited to User:A.

**Answer for question 2:**
According to the data structure,
**User:A** has invited to User:B, User:C, and User:D. **User:B** and **User:C** has accepted the invitation & User:D not accepted the invitation.

now come to the Data node of User:A, User:B and User:C has updated the data.

You can add the functionality such that if the **invitationstatus** of the Users is accepted then and then they can update or view the **Data** Node of the User:A

Still, if you have any query then let me know and if you are satisfied with the answer then upvote it and tick the green mark.
Thank You

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did clear a lot of stuff, even those which I did not even think about.... But for the **1st answer**, I don't want to show all the users available in my DB to user A to add to his list, but I want user A to send invitations through whatsapp intent to user B, C to join the group...how to achieve this? I think I would have to pass some unique ID so that B,C can accept that from their app.. And what if the users that user A wants to add to his list has not already installed my app? how to invite those?

Comment: and for the **2nd answer**, if I allow user B,C to update the DB values of User A, what should be my security conditions in **rules** in firebase console?